# Project Euler #12 help needed

Tags: java

The following code is for project euler problem 12. it is meant to find the first triangular number that has over 500 divisors but just runs endlessly. Any help would be appreciated

```
public class Problem12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[20000];
        long trinumber = 1;
        int j;

        for (int i = 1;; i++) {
            j = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k <= trinumber; k++) {

                if (trinumber % k == 0) {
                    array[j] = k;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            if (array[500] != 0) {
                System.out.println(trinumber);
                return;
            }
            trinumber += i;
            array = new int[array.length];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your algorithm is just slow. How long did it run?

Comment: its been running for at least 5 minutes

Comment: @Callum Luke Perks  did you get any output after 5 minute?

Comment: Have you tried to find the triangle number with a lower number of divisors? E.g. 5?

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating wrong sequence of triangular numbers.
The problem is here : `trinumber += i;`
Notice that the second triangular number for your case isn't 3, but 2.
You should move that line of code directly after the outermost for loop.
Also, initialize your variable `trinumber` with 0 rather than 1 : change this `long trinumber = 1;`  to this :   `long trinumber = 0;`
There is no need for your variable `array`, use a counter instead and increment it when new divisor is found, than check if that counter is equal to 500 after that.

**EDIT :**
Here is the final with the edits suggested :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        long trinumber = 0;

        for (int i = 1;; i++) {
            int numDivisors = 0;
            trinumber += i;

            for (int k = 1; k <= trinumber; k++) {

                if (trinumber % k == 0) {
                    numDivisors++;


                }
            }
            if (numDivisors > 500) {
                System.out.println(trinumber);
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                return;
            }


        }
    }
```

The number in question is  :  76576500 and that took me over 17 hours on my machine to complete. So, some mathematical hint is needed to improve the running time of this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to this program.. Hope this helps.
It took over 182 minutes on my machine running netbeans

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    long triNumber=0;
    int j=0;
    for (int n=0;;n++){
        triNumber=n*(n+1)/2;    //Triangular number calculation
        for (int i=1;i<=triNumber;i++){
            if(triNumber%i==0){
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (j>=500){
            System.out.println(triNumber);
            break;
        }
        j=0;
    }
}
```

first triangular number is 76576500 which have over 500 divisors
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 182 minutes 44 seconds)